# how to print value to corresponding key in python

Tags: python

I am trying to print the corresponding value of the keyword entered.
So if user_input == key
print(value)
No errors, but code needs to be corrected for output desired. Please help.

```
user_input = input("Type in a word to retrieve it's opposite: ")

my_dict = {
    'hot': 'cold',
    'wet': 'dry',
    'soft': 'hard',
    'tall': 'short',
    'flat': 'round',
    'skinny': 'fat'
}


for key, value in my_dict.items():
    if user_input in my_dict.keys():
        print(value)
```

Comment: print(my_dict[user_input] does print the corresponding value, but it prints the value * amount of values in dict. Example- if user_input == 'hot' output is cold,cold,cold,cold,cold,cold

Comment: ...delete the entire for loop in your code and just print (my_dict[user_name]) (or) print (my_dict.get(user_input,''))

Comment: perfect. thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
    print(my_dict[user_input])
except NameError:
    print(“Please enter valid input”)
```